# weblogic does not find .ear in stage, but it is there on the file system

Tags: deployment, weblogic, weblogic12c, ear, oracle12.2

When starting the weblogic server I get this error:
Caused By: java.io.IOException: /home/weblogic/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/mydomain/servers/managed1/stage/myear/myear.ear (No such file or directory) with : /home/weblogic/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/epersonenstand/servers/managed1/stage/myear/myear.ear

<Failed to create App/Comp MBeans for AppDeploymentMBean myear. Error - weblogic.management.DeploymentException: /home/weblogic/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/epersonenstand/servers/managed1/stage/myear/myear/myear.ear.

But the ear file is present in the folder.

Tried to redeploy it while the server is running and while it is shut down, I get always the same error(and restarting the server including the OS). The same deployment did work earlier(tried different versions), the problems started after a restart of the server(weblogic was shut down properly).

The exact weblogic version is 12.2.1.3.0 running on SLES 12R2.

Does anybody has an idea how to solve the problem?

thanks in advance,

Ben

Answer (score 0):

Does your domain have multiple machines configured?  I've seem similar errors and got confused because checking the filesystem on the admin server machine showed the files existed, but when checking the machines of other servers (eg. managed1) the file didn't exist.  The error message doesn't make it clear which machine the file can't be found on.

Comment: There is only that one machine.

Comment: other thing to check would be the user that the weblogic server is running as, has permissions to read the file and folder

Comment: we checked, the user and the permissions are ok